# SQL Manual Sortorder

Tags: sql

The below data is randomly fetched from SQL table and I want the data to be sorted in below order. How will I write SQL Query for it?

[image]

Edit: I want order by like below image.

[image: Image2]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `ORDER BY "Desc"`

Comment: Not clear. Do you you want to records to be sorted by the "Desc" column, alphabetically? Is the "SortOrder" column relevant to your request?

Comment: I am using SQL @a_horse_with_no_name ...

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a DBMS product

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: (SQL Server, MYSQL)

```
SELECT [DESC], SortOrder]
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY [DESC] DESC
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . .

```
order by length(desc) desc
```

Note:  `desc` is a reserved word in virtually all databases, so it is a bad choice for a column.  Also, `length()` may be called `len()` in some databases.

This orders by the length of the first column, in descending order.  That appears to be your sort order based on the sample data.

Comment: Please see the second Image. I want result like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT [DESC]
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY [DESC],
         CASE WHEN LEN([DESC]) - LEN(REPLACE([DESC],' ','')) = 0 THEN 1
              WHEN LEN([DESC]) - LEN(REPLACE([DESC],' ','')) = 1 THEN 2
              WHEN LEN([DESC]) - LEN(REPLACE([DESC],' ','')) = 2 THEN 3
              ELSE 4
         END
```

Comment: This is sorting it properly, but I want it to sort in other order. As shown in image 1st comes XXXXX then YYYYY. I want YYYY, then XXXX, then ther might be ZZZZ then AAAA, then CCCC, etc... so it means sortorder field with values=2 can be of manual order. How do I achieve it. I have added another pic to get clear image.

Comment: Please see the second image. How to achieve this sorting?

Comment: Can you add screen shot for my query result. since I dont have real data to test it right now ;(

Comment: The screenshot of your query gave the exact result of 1st Image. But I want result of second image. I cant share data as it is sensitive information.

Comment: Hmm Strange requirement

Comment: Any solution please...!!